# Handling event binding and callbacks within actions in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This Smells. The result of this action should register an event handlers on the page, but should I put the named function callbacks (clickHandler)? A mixin? or perhaps another class entirely.

```
App.StepController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        captureStep: function() {

            //Bind the handler to this so callback has access to Controller properties
            var clickHandler = clickHandler.bind(this);

            //Can't do this with jquery, as capture is not cross browser compatible.
            //Setting capture to true on a body event makes this event fire before all others                
            if (document.body.addEventListener) {
                document.body.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, true);
            }

            function clickHandler(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); //Needed for links/buttons
                event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Stop the event from bubbling and prevent 'same element' event handlers 

                //Determine clickTarget...

                console.log("Clicked: " +  clickTarget);
                this.set('model.targetPath', clickTarget);

                // remove this handler from the body
                document.body.removeEventListener(event.type, clickHandler, true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the clickTarget, is it the `event.targetElement`? And just to know, why do you want to store it?

Comment: clickTarget is derived from event.targetElement. Basically, there are a bunch of rules which take any element on the page and uniquely identify it. It's an embedded app installed on pages we don't control.

Answer (score 1):

Ember [views will handle the page events](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/) for you; no need to write your own event handlers:

```
App.StepView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(event) {
           this.get('controller').set(...);
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [links](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) or actions [actions](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) to handle click events.

Comment: Cool! But i need the ability to turn this handler on and off. Also, the handler must be bound to the document body, not the view. To give you some context. The user hits record, the clicks anywhere within the page, which is what I need to capture.

Comment: So setup the click handler on the ApplicationView and have it toggle a property on the ApplicationController object, or any other controller. Then you can observe that controller property.

Comment: It's an embedded app, so the application controller is bound to a div, not the body. The event handler needs to be bound to the document body to cover elements outside of the applications control.